# SQL: How to form query to combine lookup?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, one storing the index and the other store the value:

```
 id  | index1  | index2
-----+---------+-------
 1   |      1  |      2

 index  | value
--------+------
 1      | hello
 2      | world
```

I would like to make a single query which can provide me the combined view:

```
 id  | value1  | value2
-----+---------+-------
 1   |  hello  |  world
```

How could I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A `JOIN` will help here. Something like:

```
SELECT tbl_index.id, tv1.value, tv2.value FROM tbl_index 
LEFT JOIN tbl_values AS tv1 ON tbl_index.index1=tv1.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_values AS tv2 ON tbl_index.index2=tv2.id
WHERE tbl_index.id=$desired_id
```

What it does is for each of the `index1` and `index2` values of a row in tbl_index, fetches the matching value from tbl_values.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Select indexTable.id, tabele1.value,table2.value
from indextable
inner join table1 on table1.id=indextable.index1
inner join table2 on table2.id=indextable.index2